# Displaying Text over VLC Video Output by Python/PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, vlc

I wonder how I can display text over my VLC video output. Every widget I put on top of the video surface widget vanishes as soon as video is played. For example, I use a QFrame as the video surface and put a Qlabel inside that QFrame. The text appears over the frame, but come video it's gone. In the following MRE, as soon as I unremark the `self.Player.play()` the video is played and the text is gone.

```
import sys 
import vlc
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget,QApplication,QMainWindow,QFrame,QLabel,QVBoxLayout

class Player(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Player,self).__init__()
        self.Init_Gui()
    #   self.Player.play()

    def Init_Gui(self):
        centralWidget = QWidget()
        mainlayout = QVBoxLayout(centralWidget)
        self.resize(640,480)
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)
        self.VideoSurface = QFrame()
        self.VideoSurface.setStyleSheet('background-color: black')

        self.OSDLabel = QLabel(self.VideoSurface)
        self.OSDLabel.setStyleSheet('color: white')
        font = QFont()
        font.setPointSize(18)
        self.OSDLabel.setFont(font)
        self.OSDLabel.setText('Testing ....... Testing..... Testing.....')

        mainlayout.addWidget(self.VideoSurface)
        self.Instance = vlc.Instance()
        self.Player = self.Instance.media_player_new('e:/media/vid1.mp4')
        self.Player.set_hwnd(self.VideoSurface.winId())
        self.show()

if __name__=='__main__':
    MyApp = QApplication(sys.argv)
    MyGui = Player()
    sys.exit(MyApp.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

libvlc has a function for that, see https://github.com/oaubert/python-vlc/blob/d64c2e84093e1b60b45d8cbb84a53bc5608a1f15/generator/templates/footer.py#L180

```
player.video_set_marquee_string
```

Comment: Thanks. I know about the marquee and have used it. I need something more 'freely' customizable. And, it's not always going to be vlc. I need a generalized solution.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "more freely" and your question is specifically regarding VLC usage. So please update it to clarify what you're asking

Comment: I mean I need something more than what the VLC module offers. I may someday want to do the same thing on another video rendering module/camera/... that does not provide a marquee option.

Comment: you won't easily find a tool or lib which can write on any video integrated control or window i'm afraid

Comment: Yeah, that's what I guessed. I will stick with the marquee for now. Yet hope remains. You never know. I would appreciate any kind of information or guidance on this matter.